# Zero-cycles on an arithmetic surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request, chow-groups, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Could anyone give a reference for the following statement, which I believe is true.

"Let X be a regular scheme, flat over $Spec( \mathbb{Z}) $, with fiber dimension $1$. Then the Chow group $CH^2(X)$ is finite."

Answer (score 4):

The finiteness is known; see [Szamuely's Seminaire Bourbaki expose](http://www.renyi.hu/~szamuely/bour09.pdf) and Remarque 3.4 (5) on page 11 is a precise reference.

Comment: A similar result is valid for any regular scheme $X$ of finite type over $\mathop{\rm Spec}(\mathbb Z)$: the Chow group
of zero cycles is finite, with the exceptions
of schemes which are proper over a finite field~$\mathbb F_p$
for which the Chow group of zero cycles has the form $\mathbb Z\oplus G$, for some finite group $G$.

This is a part of geometric class field theory, 
due to Rosenlicht, Lang (50s), Bloch (1981), Kato-Saito (1986)... 
Szamuely's Seminaire Bourbaki explains the new point of view given by work of Wiesend.